# Error reg. Liberty file reading at ABC stage

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am using a liberty file which is already tested on different synthesis tools.Its working fine.But when I am trying to use it here, an error is displayed below

Flow steps Followed:

```
[leela@ins108 exp]$ yosys

 /----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
 |                                                                            |
 |  yosys -- Yosys Open SYnthesis Suite                                       |
 |                                                                            |
 |  Copyright (C) 2012 - 2015  Clifford Wolf <clifford@clifford.at>           |
 |                                                                            |
 |  Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any  |
 |  purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above    |
 |  copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.         |
 |                                                                            |
 |  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES  |
 |  WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF          |
 |  MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR   |
 |  ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES    |
 |  WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN     |
 |  ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF   |
 |  OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.            |
 |                                                                            |
 \----------------------------------------------------------------------------/

 Yosys 0.5 (git sha1 UNKNOWN, clang 3.4.2 -fPIC -Os)


yosys> read_verilog top.v submod1.v submod2.v bottom2.v 
1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend.
Parsing Verilog input from `top.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\top'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

2. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend.
Parsing Verilog input from `submod1.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\submod1'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

3. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend.
Parsing Verilog input from `submod2.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\submod2'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

4. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend.
Parsing Verilog input from `bottom2.v' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\bottom2'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

yosys> hierarchy -check -top top

5. Executing HIERARCHY pass (managing design hierarchy).
Top module:  \top
Used module:     \submod2
Used module:         \bottom2
Used module:     \submod1
Removed 0 unused modules.
Mapping positional arguments of cell submod2.bottom2i (bottom2).

yosys> proc

6. Executing PROC pass (convert processes to netlists).

6.1. Executing PROC_CLEAN pass (remove empty switches from decision trees).
Cleaned up 0 empty switches.

6.2. Executing PROC_RMDEAD pass (remove dead branches from decision trees).
Removed a total of 0 dead cases.

6.3. Executing PROC_INIT pass (extract init attributes).

6.4. Executing PROC_ARST pass (detect async resets in processes).

6.5. Executing PROC_MUX pass (convert decision trees to multiplexers).
Creating decoders for process `\bottom2.$proc$bottom2.v:15$7'.
  creating decoder for signal `$0\areg[6:0]'.
  creating decoder for signal `$0\breg[6:0]'.
Creating decoders for process `\submod2.$proc$submod2.v:13$5'.
  creating decoder for signal `$0\creg[3:0]'.
Creating decoders for process `\submod1.$proc$submod1.v:9$2'.
  creating decoder for signal `$0\do[6:0]'.
Creating decoders for process `\top.$proc$top.v:14$1'.
  creating decoder for signal `$0\ireg[4:0]'.

6.6. Executing PROC_DFF pass (convert process syncs to FFs).
Creating register for signal `\bottom2.\areg' using process `\bottom2.$proc$bottom2.v:15$7'.
  created $dff cell `$procdff$36' with positive edge clock.
Creating register for signal `\bottom2.\breg' using process `\bottom2.$proc$bottom2.v:15$7'.
  created $dff cell `$procdff$37' with positive edge clock.
Creating register for signal `\submod2.\creg' using process `\submod2.$proc$submod2.v:13$5'.
  created $dff cell `$procdff$38' with positive edge clock.
Creating register for signal `\submod1.\do' using process `\submod1.$proc$submod1.v:9$2'.
  created $dff cell `$procdff$39' with positive edge clock.
Creating register for signal `\top.\ireg' using process `\top.$proc$top.v:14$1'.
  created $dff cell `$procdff$40' with positive edge clock.

6.7. Executing PROC_CLEAN pass (remove empty switches from decision trees).
Found and cleaned up 4 empty switches in `\bottom2.$proc$bottom2.v:15$7'.
Removing empty process `bottom2.$proc$bottom2.v:15$7'.
Removing empty process `submod2.$proc$submod2.v:13$5'.
Removing empty process `submod1.$proc$submod1.v:9$2'.
Removing empty process `top.$proc$top.v:14$1'.
Cleaned up 4 empty switches.

yosys> opt

7. Executing OPT pass (performing simple optimizations).

7.1. Executing OPT_CONST pass (perform const folding).

7.2. Executing OPT_SHARE pass (detect identical cells).
Finding identical cells in module `\bottom2'.
Finding identical cells in module `\submod2'.
Finding identical cells in module `\submod1'.
Finding identical cells in module `\top'.
Removed a total of 0 cells.

7.3. Executing OPT_MUXTREE pass (detect dead branches in mux trees).
Running muxtree optimizier on module \bottom2..
  Creating internal representation of mux trees.
  Evaluating internal representation of mux trees.
    Root of a mux tree: $procmux$34 (pure)
    Root of a mux tree: $procmux$22 (pure)
    Root of a mux tree: $ternary$bottom2.v:13$6 (pure)
  Analyzing evaluation results.
Running muxtree optimizier on module \submod2..
  Creating internal representation of mux trees.
  Evaluating internal representation of mux trees.
    Root of a mux tree: $ternary$submod2.v:9$4 (pure)
  Analyzing evaluation results.
Running muxtree optimizier on module \submod1..
  Creating internal representation of mux trees.
  Evaluating internal representation of mux trees.
    Root of a mux tree: $ternary$submod1.v:10$3 (pure)
  Analyzing evaluation results.
Running muxtree optimizier on module \top..
  Creating internal representation of mux trees.
  No muxes found in this module.
Removed 0 multiplexer ports.

7.4. Executing OPT_REDUCE pass (consolidate $*mux and $reduce_* inputs).
  Optimizing cells in module \bottom2.
  Optimizing cells in module \submod2.
  Optimizing cells in module \submod1.
  Optimizing cells in module \top.
Performed a total of 0 changes.

7.5. Executing OPT_SHARE pass (detect identical cells).
Finding identical cells in module `\bottom2'.
Finding identical cells in module `\submod2'.
Finding identical cells in module `\submod1'.
Finding identical cells in module `\top'.
Removed a total of 0 cells.

7.6. Executing OPT_RMDFF pass (remove dff with constant values).
Replaced 0 DFF cells.

7.7. Executing OPT_CLEAN pass (remove unused cells and wires).
Finding unused cells or wires in module \bottom2..
Finding unused cells or wires in module \submod2..
Finding unused cells or wires in module \submod1..
Finding unused cells or wires in module \top..

7.8. Executing OPT_CONST pass (perform const folding).

7.9. Finished OPT passes. (There is nothing left to do.)

yosys> techmap 

8. Executing TECHMAP pass (map to technology primitives).

8.1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend.
Parsing Verilog input from `<techmap.v>' to AST representation.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_bool_ops'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_reduce_ops'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_logic_ops'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_compare_ops'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_various'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_simplemap_registers'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_shift_ops_shr_shl_sshl_sshr'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_shift_shiftx'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_fa'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_lcu'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_alu'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_macc'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_alumacc'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\$__div_mod_u'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\$__div_mod'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_div'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_mod'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_pow'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_pmux'.
Generating RTLIL representation for module `\_90_lut'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.
Mapping top.$procdff$40 ($dff) with simplemap.
Mapping submod1.$ternary$submod1.v:10$3 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping submod1.$procdff$39 ($dff) with simplemap.
Mapping submod2.$ternary$submod2.v:9$4 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping submod2.$procdff$38 ($dff) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$13 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$ternary$bottom2.v:13$6 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$eq$bottom2.v:17$8 ($eq) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$eq$bottom2.v:22$9 ($eq) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$eq$bottom2.v:27$10 ($eq) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$eq$bottom2.v:32$11 ($eq) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$16 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$19 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$22 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$25 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$28 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$31 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procmux$34 ($mux) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procdff$36 ($dff) with simplemap.
Mapping bottom2.$procdff$37 ($dff) with simplemap.
No more expansions possible.

yosys> dfflibmap -liberty scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib 

9. Executing DFFLIBMAP pass (mapping DFF cells to sequential cells from liberty file).
  final dff cell mappings:
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_N_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_P_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_NN0_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_NN1_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_NP0_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_NP1_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_PN0_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_PN1_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_PP0_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFF_PP1_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_NNN_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_NNP_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_NPN_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_NPP_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_PNN_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_PNP_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_PPN_
    unmapped dff cell: $_DFFSR_PPP_
Mapping DFF cells in module `\bottom2':
Mapping DFF cells in module `\submod2':
Mapping DFF cells in module `\submod1':
Mapping DFF cells in module `\top':

yosys> abc -liberty scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib 

10. Executing ABC pass (technology mapping using ABC).

10.1. Extracting gate netlist of module `\bottom2' to `<abc-temp-dir>/input.blif'..
Extracted 79 gates and 105 wires to a netlist network with 24 inputs and 21 outputs.

10.1.1. Executing ABC.
Running ABC command: <yosys-exe-dir>/yosys-abc -s -f <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script 2>&1
ABC: ABC command line: "source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script".
ABC: 
ABC: + read_blif <abc-temp-dir>/input.blif 
ABC: + read_lib -w /home/leela/synth/exp/scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib 
ABC: Reading SCL library from file "/home/leela/synth/exp/scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib" has failed. 
ABC: ** cmd error: aborting 'source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script'
ABC: File "/home/leela/synth/exp/scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib". Line  64611. Failed to parse entry "".
ABC: Parsing failed.  Parsing time =     0.10 sec
ABC: Table cannot be found
ABC: Memory =    4.80 MB. Time =     0.15 sec
ERROR: Can't open ABC output file `/tmp/yosys-abc-6GrNPU/output.blif'.
```

It is failing at stage "abc". 
Hope you understand the issue.

Can you please guide me to clear this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently ABC cannot parse your liberty file:

```
ABC: Reading SCL library from file "/home/leela/synth/exp/scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib" has failed. 
ABC: ** cmd error: aborting 'source <abc-temp-dir>/abc.script'
ABC: File "/home/leela/synth/exp/scadv12atk_cmos10sf_hvt_ss_0p9v_125c.lib". Line  64611. Failed to parse entry "".
ABC: Parsing failed.  Parsing time =     0.10 sec
```

Without a copy of the liberty file it is impossible to tell what upset ABC in line 64611.

Comment: Hi,Can u tell me the procedure to upload the file as I am new to this kind of stuff..Hope you respond as soon as possible.

Comment: @user2423862 afaik it is not possible to upload files on stackoverflow. You can upload it for example to http://pastebin.com/ or https://www.google.com/drive/ and then post the link here.

Comment: @user2423862 I just realized you are using Yosys 0.5. You can try latest git head. There have been fixes to Yosys and ABC for liberty files with empty statements (additional semicolons) recently.

Comment: Hi,I am using the latest version mentioned in yosys site.Can u please provide me the link if latest is available..  liberty file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sMNYR0egOEdW1jMXVHcVFfd1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2423862 There are two problems with this liberty file: 1.) it contains fewer { than }, thus is syntactically invalid, and 2.) it does not contain a general-purpose cell library: all 36 cells in that liberty file seem to be special purpose cells like full adders. This liberty file clearly is not meant to be used as target for logic synthesis. (Regarding git head version of yosys: Simply follow the instructions for "Building Development Sources" on http://www.clifford.at/yosys/download.html.)